# How to make a shape follow a row when sorting?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I've created a macro that I assigned to a shape, which allows me to click on the shape to hide or show a picture. This works great !

**What I want to do now is link this shape to a row of a spreadsheet, in a way that when I sort my spreadsheet, my shape follows the same row. It currently stays on the same cell when I sort** (I do select all of the cells when I sort)

*What I've tried so far :*

-I have right clicked and set the properties of the shape to "move and size with cells".    This does not prevent the problem.

-Typing "*=the_name_of_the_cell*" into the cell containing the shape, but it doesnt work.

Thanks in advance !

edit : rephrased it

Comment: NOT CLEAR.........do you want the Shape to move or remain fixed??

Comment: Are you including the cell under the top left corner of the shape in the sort range?

Comment: Sorry I realize I wasnt clear :
I want my shape to move just as the other rows when I sort differently.
As of now, it simply doesnt move, so i want it to "follow" the same line or "stay" with the same line. **Thanks a lot for your fast answers/comments, you guys are really helpful !**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shape's .Left and .Top properties to move it to a fixed range on your worksheet. To keep it in a certain row you need only the .Top property.

The following example assumes you want to keep a shape called "Example" on row 7:

```
ActiveWorksheet.Shapes("Example").Top = ActiveWorksheet.Range("7:7").Top
```

Comment: I rephrased my question upon realizing it was unclear. My problem is the opposite : I want my shape to move with the line when I sort, but it doesn't.

Comment: In this case, you will need to provide more information on what data you're sorting and how you're sorting it.

Comment: Sure. The whole spreadsheet is sorted this way : 1st : Alphabetical order on column D, 2nd : I have to frequently switch between Alphabetical order on column E, F or G.

Comment: In case this is relevant, this is how I created my macroed shape : http://www.get-digital-help.com/2013/10/25/show-and-hide-a-picture-vba/

Comment: I assume the row the shape is supposed to stay with is part of the table you are sorting. Does that row then contain a unique value in either column D, E, F of G?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of a part of my sheet. They do not contain any unique value. No matter what the sorting type is, my shape always stays on M4. http://imgur.com/X6qxcxT ------ Thanks again for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The shape's property of `Move and size with cells` will work, but the shape has to precisely fit inside a single-cell for this to work when sorting.

Click the shape, hold the `Alt` key and resize each of the corners. It should snap into each of the cell's corners (with a little care). Increase the Zoom if it helps.

Comment: It seems pretty snapped to me, but it still doesn't move when I sort differently : http://imgur.com/KgBf4LG  Note : the "resize" function has always been working, the shape changes size as the column does.

Comment: I would cut and paste it back in, or shrink it first, and resize it again - Excel is a bit fussy about it. However, is that cell in the sortable area of a table? It looks to be separated from it.

Comment: I cut it and pasted it right in the middle of the table and resorting still doesnt do anything. (the "Move and size with cells" property was checked when I sorted). It was a good idea though :(

Answer (score 0):

Hide some text in the cell behind your shape and it should follow with your sort.  That worked for me.  I also have the shape properties set to "Move and Size With Cells".  For example, I have a DELETE button on my row.  The button text says "DELETE". The button shape is small and fits in one cell, and so behind it, I typed the word DELETE. The button shape covers it so no one can see it and I also made the font color WHITE so it will not show when printed.